# Create Couchbase documents via REST API

Tags: couchbase

I am new to Couchbase and I want to know about how CRUD can be achieved in it.

I have sucessfully created a bucket and I've tried to insert documents in it using CURL.

**Creating a bucket using CURL succeeded like the following**:
`curl -X POST -u admin:citrus -d name=test-bucket -d ramQuotaMB=100 -d authType=none -d replicaNumber=2 -d proxyPort=11216 http://example.com:8091/pools/default/buckets`

Now how can I create sample documents in this bucket?

How can I achieve this by using a REST API, please help me..

Answer (score 4):

Couchbase isn't designed to use a REST API for data creation or mutation, perhaps you are thinking of CouchDB which does offer this and shares some similarities with Couchbase although they are distinct technologies.

You need to use one of the sdks to interact with your bucket, there are a multitude of SDK's available in all the major languages, Java,Ruby,Python,C etc.  Check out the list of them here, they also contain getting started guides which covers the basic operations such as get/set and more complex examples of views and topics such as locking.

http://docs.couchbase.com/

Comment: Hey @PRASANTHMV if this answered your question would you accept it please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the Sync Gateway of Couchbase. The Sync Gateway provides a REST API which allows you to Create, Read, Update and Delete (CRUD) documents.

For example, if you have a Couchbase Server running on port 8091 with a bucket called `test-bucket`, you can set up your Sync Gateway with the following content in your `sync_gateway.json` configuration file:

`{
        "log": ["HTTP+"],
        "adminInterface": "127.0.0.1:4985",
        "interface": "0.0.0.0:4984",
        "databases": {
                "test-db": {
                        "server": "http://localhost:8091",
                        "bucket": "test-bucket",
                        "username": "test-bucket",
                        "password": "test-bucket-password",
                        "users": {
                                "GUEST": {"disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] }
                        }
                }
        }
}`

Then, after starting the Sync Gateway, you can create a document like the following:

`curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:4984/test-db/myNewDocId -d @document.file`

With `document.file` being a file with the JSON content of the document you'd like to create and with `myNewDocId` being the ID of the new document.

You can find all supported REST API methods and details in the official documentation: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/document/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase now supports adding document via  curl call.

you can do

```
curl localhost:8093/query/service -u uname:paaswd -d 'statement=INSERT INTO `bucketName` (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ( "my_doc_id",  {"Price":"price"} );'
```

Note we are using 8093 which is query service port. for this to run you have to have query service(n1ql) running.

Comment: This works indeed, but if you have plus signs (+) in your -d parameter, it gets converted to whitespace characters.